# Regex to get a count of strings that match the pattern

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I want to count the number of occurrences of the below format of string in notepad++.

```
name="*" lastName="*"
```

(* represents it can be any name/lastName)

I am using the following regex

```
/name="([A-Z])\w" lastName="([A-Z])\w"
```

I am not able to figure out how to give hard coded values as a part of regex.

Comment: notepad++ isn't a programming language. You might want to specify outside the tags that you're using Java. Also what have you tried?

Comment: I am using count feature of notepad++ to count the occurrences. 
We can give a regular expression in notepad++ and count the occurrences.

Comment: @tushar, have you solve your problem with my solution on notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad ++ solution is:     `name=".*" lastName=".*"`

[image]

Comment: This was my very first try. but it did not yield me any result before posting the question.

name="*"* lastName="*"  this was my regular expression. Note that there is one more star in between name and lastName